# How to edit for existing shipping addresses in checkout page magento2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, shipping-address

How to edit the existing shipping address in checkout page. Magento2 have edit address option for only new added shipping address.

> Magento\Customer\view\frontend\web\js\model\customer\address.js

```
 isEditable: function ()
 {
 return true;       
  },
```

Edit button is showing for existing shipping addresses. Please find the screenshot.

Display existing shipping address data in popup when click on respective existing shipping address Edit button.

But new shipping address is displaying instead of existing shipping address when click on existing shipping address.

How to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I am also getting this issue. Did you solve this ?

Comment: @Ajesh were you able to find solution

Comment: Also interested in if there was a solution to this

Comment: Please Upgrade to Magento version 2.4.4. They Have Solved that issue.

Answer (score -1):

Please Upgrade to Magento version 2.4.4. They Have Solved that issue.
=> could u please let me know how can i edit an exist address on checkout page with M2.4.4?

Comment: Actually not. What is fixed in Magento 2.4.4 is that if add a new shipping address and edit this the data of the new shipping address will be prefilled: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/87f0be780bea7b3dba3cbfc1c30ed4325da332cd

But if you enable editing of the already existing address only the name is prefilled.